# How to debug the loading of ActiveX controls

Tags: internet-explorer, vb6, activex

I have a very peculiar and specific case. I develop a VB6 based ActiveX control that I need to work on a different one.

The development machine is a Windows Server 2003, the "production" machine is Windows 7 Prof.

Now, when I package by ActiveX in CAB and run the "demo" HTM-file on the development machine, everything works fine.

But as soon as I copy alle the contents to my production machine, and open the same HTM file (after clicking OK on the ActiveX security warnings and "installing" the CAB), nothing happens (where it should actually open a message box).

How can I debug this? Obvously, the browser does find the CAB, otherwise it wouldn't even know what to install. But, it doesn't seem to trigger correctly.

My problem isn't so much that I didn't know how to handle errors, but *where these errors are*? Is there any "Internet Explorer Logfile" that I don't know of?

Comment: Did you include a license package (.LPK) file?

Comment: See http://support.microsoft.com/kb/159923/en-us

Comment: Run Process Monitor to rule out obvious issues like failed COM registration, file permission, or per-user registration of a dependency.

Comment: I ran the process monitor and it shows mainly registry queries. Of those, most are `SUCCESS` and some are `NAME NOT FOUND`. These are e.g. for `FontSubstitues` and `DefAuthLevel`... what does that tell me?

Comment: Compare with the log from a machine where the ActiveX is working and see if there is any mismatch between SUCCESS and NAME NOT FOUND, or OK and ACCESS DENIED.

Comment: I can't find any differences there... The `NAME NOT FOUND` appears on the other machine, too.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After some more research, I found the error. In my enthusiasm for 64bit and the like, I made the 64bit version of IE my default, resulting that I always loaded the demo page with my ActiveX on that browser.

As I know now, [this won't work](https://superuser.com/questions/443954/vb6-ocx-not-working-in-window-7-64bit-ie), because VB6 only compiles to 32bit.

Loading the page in the 32bit version showed that the ActiveX could be loaded and run without problems.

Sorry for the confusion. I tend to forget that 64bit is my default and that, obviously, old languages won't always work with that.

Answer (score -1):

you have the system log Windows Logs->System and look for AxInstSV. see what that has to say. Also you can use the process monitor (PRocMon) to see what kicks in. I presume youve checked to 
see if vb6 exe works at all on a windows7 machine.

A vanilla win7 will not run VB6 it is missing the runtime files for VB

Comment: How would I check if my machine can run VB6?

Comment: Windows 7 (and even Windows 8) includes the VB6 runtime files.  See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vstudio/ms788708.aspx

Comment: Sorry that is right, I tested this when the win7 beta came out and all our ancient stuff broke. And today its the same. The runtime is there but the only solution for us was using a xp virtual machine.